# Sorting a doubly linked list from low to high

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have to sort my list as I add numbers to it but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. If I input `9,5,7`, it prints out `7,5,9`. So I'm assuming it's adding to the front of the list?

This is what I have so far to sort the list:

```
if (Head == NULL)
{
    Head = newNode;
    newNode->prev = Head;
}
else
{
    Node *curr = Head;
    while (curr->next != NULL && curr->next->data < newNode->data )
    {
        curr->next = curr;
    }

    if (curr == Head)
    {
        Head = newNode;
        curr->prev = newNode;
        newNode->next = curr;
        newNode->prev = Head;
    }
    else if (curr->next != NULL)
    {
        curr->prev->next = newNode;
        newNode->prev = curr;
        newNode->next = curr->next;
        curr->next->prev = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->prev = curr;
        curr->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: *So I'm assuming its adding to the front of the list*  -- Why assume?  Debug your code to see what is going on.

Comment: You're not inserting things into the list properly, not even when it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

to start correct this:

```
while (curr->next != NULL && curr->next->data < newNode->data )
{
    curr=curr->next;
}
```